# Symfony 3 : Change the locale for all pages

Tags: php, locale, symfony

I would like to change the locale for all pages on symfony.

I tried this : `$req->setLocale('fr');`

But when I go to an other page the locale is set as default again.

I know that it is possible to do it with the link "domaine/fr/get" but I don't want to have different links for each languages... :/

I was also wondering if it is possible to set the default locale depending on the ip's country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by Setting the [Default Locale.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#setting-a-default-locale)

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    default_locale: fr
```

To get some advanced control on how to make the Locale Sticky during a user's session or even set the Locale based on IP, you can create a `LocaleListener` , which is covered in this [cookbook entry.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html)

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to change the default locale. I want to let the user the possibility to change manually the language. The webpage will always be in english but if a french guy comes he can click on the french flag and the whole webpage will be set in french during his session.

Comment: A LocaleListener but it didn't change anything :/

Comment: Alright a achieved to do it with the fr in the link. It will be okay like that for the moment. But in the app/routing.yml when I put requirements for the _locale, it returns me an error :/